# Undefined index: name calling using PUT http

Tags: php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

I use postman do a POST this worked, but how about PUT?

This won't work

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo $_PUT['name'];
?>
```

I tried echo $_POST['name']; with PUT request, I got Undefined index: name

My postman screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1lWT.png

Comment: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/

Comment: If you have used postman then copy the pho code generated there to achieve what you're looking for.. the code you have given here is not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @NareshKumar https://i.imgur.com/PVf1b2c.png

Comment: Ok so is this your edit.php script or post.php script? for post.php(the one from where you make call) can be obtained by clicking on **code** button in postman and choosing language as php. If you are looking for edit.php then you should first make the call from post.php so that the edit php will get populated with result. It's good if you gothrough restAPI docs for php

Comment: afaik there is no `$_PUT` in PHP

Comment: @RamRaider then why $_POST doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP to use the `PUT` method you need to delve into the `stdin` stream rather than rely upon the readily available `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST` arrays.

From the [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) you will find more information and to plagarise their first example might help.

```
<?php

    /* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
    $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

    print_r( $putdata );
?>
```